How to add JP2 store to GeoServer
I have GeoServer 2.25 with the GDAL extension.  According to GeoServer's documentation this should be enough to get support for JP2, but I do not see JP2 as an option when trying to create a new Store.
How can you add JP2 raster stores into GeoServer?

Does your gdal have jp2k compiled in?

@IanTurton, yes, it supports JP2OpenJPEG.  i can convert tif to jp2 via command line.

And that is the gdal that GeoServer is using?

@IanTurton, I'm assuming so... It's the only one in the path. How to tell?

There are (or used to be) instructions in the plugin setup documentation. Basically it's the one with the jni wrapper.
